# How can I download an mp4 straight to my hard drive in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, download

I'm using this code to download an mp4 file:

```
func downloadImageFile() {
    let myURLstring = getImageURLCM()
    let myFilePathString = "/Users/jack/Desktop/Comics/"+getTitle()+".mp4"

    let url = NSURL(string: myURLstring)
    let dataFromURL = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    fileManager.createFileAtPath(myFilePathString, contents: dataFromURL, attributes: nil)
}
```

But I've noticed that the file actually gets loaded up into my *RAM* first, before the `NSFileManager` saves it to my hard drive (based on the `Xcode` debug session). That's tolerable for smaller files, but most of the files I want to download with this will be at least `1GB`.

My main question is: how to make this more RAM friendly?

I've also noticed that I get the spinning wheel of death until the download is finished, so if advice on fixing that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better to go with the system managed download in NSURLSession, specifically NSURLDownloadTask. This way you don't have to worry about memory management of large downloads.  From NSURLSession swift file

```
     /*
     * download task convenience methods.  When a download successfully
     * completes, the NSURL will point to a file that must be read or
     * copied during the invocation of the completion routine.  The file
     * will be removed automatically.
     */

    func downloadTaskWithURL(url: NSURL, completionHandler: (NSURL?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDownloadTask?
```

Example of Use below - copy and paste into new Swift Playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

func downloadFile(filePath: String) {

    let url = NSURL(string: filePath)

    if let unwrappedURL = url {

        let downloadTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(unwrappedURL) { (urlToCompletedFile, reponse, error) -> Void in

            // unwrap error if present
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                print(unwrappedError)
            }
            else {

                if let unwrappedURLToCachedCompletedFile = urlToCompletedFile {

                    print(unwrappedURLToCachedCompletedFile)

                    // Copy this file to your destinationURL with
                    //NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL
                }
            }
        }
        downloadTask?.resume()
    }
}

downloadFile("http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/711y6zlz0ll/711/711_networking_with_nsurlsession.pdf?dl=1")

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()
```

Simple Example on github here - https://github.com/serendipityapps/NSURLSessionDownloadTaskExample

Comment: I can't get this to work. I can't see anything happening on the network when it's run.

Comment: I have changed code example to a swift playground example that I just verified definitely works

Comment: That works perfectly! Now I'm trying to use this line to copy the file over, but the file doesn't get copied: `NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(unwrappedURLToCachedCompletedFile, toURL: destinationURL!, error: nil)` any ideas?

Comment: Hi, see link added in answer to github example project

Answer (score 1):

```
dataFromURL.writeToFile(myFilePathString, atomically: true)
```

This is the snippet I use, it writes the loaded data into the file at the given path.